# Working with $i$ and finding roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you find the cubic polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients, where $1-3i$ and $-2$ are the roots of $f(x)$?

It has been too long since I have worked with $i$ and I have been unable to generate it.

Comment: Hint: The third  root is $1+3i$.

Comment: **Hint** *conjugate* roots, e.g. see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/51547/242) and [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/770111/242)

Answer (score 1):

The thing to realize is that roots occur in conjugate pairs. So, if $1-3i$ is one root, then $1+3i$ is another root. Hence, the polynomial can be formed by multiplying out

$$(x-(1-3i))(x-(1+3i))(x-(-2)).$$

Answer (score 1):

For real coefficients, we must have either real roots, or roots that are complex conjugate pairs.

Inasmuch as $1-i3$ is a root, then $1+i3$ must also be.

The cubic polynomial has the form

$$a(z+2)(z-1+i3)(z-1-i3)=a(z+2)(z^2-2z+10)=a(z^3+6z+20)$$

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate root theorem tells us that for a polynomial f(x) with real coefficients, if a+bi is a root, then a-bi is also a root.

Therefore 1-3i must also be a root. 
Thus, you may multiply the roots together in the form (x-r1)(x-r2)(x-r3) to obtain the required polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions correctly point out that the third root must be $1+3i$, and therefore the polynomial must be $$(x-(1-3i))(x-(1+3i))(x-2)$$
or a multiple of it (notice that multiplying through the entire thing by a constant does not change the zeroes).

I will add to this one tip for simplifying the expression:  Notice that you can regroup and multiply out the factors that involve $i$ as follows:
$$(x-(1-3i))(x-(1+3i)) = ((x-1) + 3i)((x-1) - 3i) = (x-1)^2 + 9$$
which might make the problem slightly easier to complete.